# SWIFT : Basic Loops and Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops

Can I put this in a loop instead of having to manually code it in for each chapter?

```
                var chp1 = Array(Chapters[0].componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
                var chp2 = Array(Chapters[1].componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
                var chp3 = Array(Chapters[2].componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
                var chp4 = Array(Chapters[3].componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
                var chp5 = Array(Chapters[4].componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
                var chp6 = Array(Chapters[5].componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
                var chp7 = Array(Chapters[6].componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
                var chp8 = Array(Chapters[7].componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use

```
var chp = []

for chapter in Chapters
{
    chp.append(chapter.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")))
}
```

now you can access to the chapters like

```
chp[0]
chp[1]
chp[2]
```

Also you don't need to cast return value to Array.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not too sure how i'd organise it tho. read the books but still not getting it :/

Comment: ` for i in Chapters[i]{
                        i = Array(Chapters[i].componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
                        return i
                    }`

Answer (score 2):

```
for range in 0...8 {
    var chp = Chapters[range]
    let result = chp.componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
}
```

Or

```
for (_, chapter) in Chapters.enumerate() {
    let result = chapter.componentsSeparatedByString("\n"))
}
```